# C# SortableList not sorting in DataGridView

Tags: c#, sorting, datagridview, iqueryable

I have a generic form for displaying a list of items. This is usually an "IQueryable" based on a Linq-2-sql query, but I want to be able to show any list. I've added code to my project so I can use SortableLists instead of the normal List, which does not support sorting by default. I can pass the Sortable list as IQueryable, but as a result sorting wont working. Is there a way to make the SortableList IQueryable while keeping it sortable?

Comment: You can sort the Iqueryable

Comment: Where do you want to sort? What do you mean by any list? please clarify

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found a solution myself: Instead of using the IQueryable directly as the datsource of  the grid (which I do with Linq-to-sql queries), I make a new SortableList by doing "new SortableList(myQuery.ToList())" and use that as datasource. And voila, it sorts.

(So, no you cannot (always) sort the IQueryable.)